# SSIS Transfer SQL Server Objects Task loses accents in transferred data

Tags: ssis, codepages

I have an SSIS package with a Transfer SQL Server Objects Task step that transfers tables (schema and data) from one database to another.
The source and the destionation databases have different collation. (I don't know whether it's relevant info.)

In some test environments some characters (Hungarian-specific accented chars: ő,ű) are converted to non-accented ones (o,u) during the transfer. In other test environments everything's fine (Hungarian accented characters are transferred well). The source table columns are non-unicode (varchar) and we cannot change it because it's a legacy system.

Experiments indicate that this behavior depends on the Windows locale setting (Control Panel / Region and Language / Administrative / "Language for non-Unicode programs"). If set to Hungarian then everything's fine, but if it's set to English then Hungarian accents are lost.

The problem is that I cannot enforce a specific Windows locale setting, so I'm looking for a way to make it right that does not depend on Windows locale.

Is there a way to tell SSIS to use Hungarian codepage in the transfer?

Comment: Just guessing here, what if you changed your process. Exclude tables that have Hungarian characters from the transfer object step. Then write the same transfer logic in a package. When you extract the data from a table, rather than select the table in a drop down, write a custom select statement to cast that data into nvarchar fields. That *might* preserve the characters. If you want to see an example, I can bang one out.

Comment: I've made a workaround. Dropped SSIS and now I'm using a stored proc that makes an INSERT INTO + SELECT through a linked server. Accents are preserved even with English locale so it's fine. But I'm still curious if it can be made with SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

In the objects page of the Transer SQL Objects task, there is an option called UseCollation. If you select this option then it should use the collation of the sour data.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not solve the problem. The target columns were created using the source collation, but the Hungarian accents were lost anyway. I guess the accent-losing conversion from Ascii to Unicode happens when the data is read from the source.